# How to use LOWER() on elements of a jsonb column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, subquery, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL table like this one:

```
Table t

id | keys (jsonb)
---+----------------
 1 | ["Key1", "Key2"]
```

My goal is to query this table to find out if one of the keys of a list is contained in the jsonb array column "keys".

---

I managed to get a result using:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE keys ?| Array ['Key1', 'Key2'];
```

I can not find a way to make this query broader by applying a lower() on the "keys" values in the table though.

Is there a way to iterate over elements to apply the lower() on each one?

Comment: `jsonb_array_elements_text`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction, jsonb_array_elements_text was indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the replies above I managed to find a way to do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t, jsonb_array_elements_text(keys) key
WHERE lower(key) in ('key1', 'key2') ;
```

Comment: You might want to `SELET t.*` to avoid getting the matched `key` (unless you want that, of course), and notice that this might return the same row multiple times in case there are duplicates in the `keys` array or matches against multiple terms.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in my case it does not really matter as I will return a boolean if a match is found (count > 0).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to unnest both arrays:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.keys) k1(val)
    inner join unnest(array['Key1', 'Key2']) k2(val)
        on lower(k1.val) = lower(k2.val)
)
```